# Add Values to a pre-builded array

Tags: arrays, swiftui, var, init, picker

I have a model and a manager that correctly add personal informations for an user, such as name, address, etc. Everything goes in my storage array and run perfectly.
Now I have to add a new section in which every user make some tests, choosing a value from a picker.

This is the code of my textview sheet in which my result is saved in **risultatoRG** variable. How can I now add this result to the user data?

TestView file:

```
struct TestView: View {
@State var isTestPressed2 = false
@Binding var dismissFlag2 : Bool
@State var isAlertOut2 = false
@State var valoreTestSelected = 0
var valoreTest : [String] = ["300", "280", "260", "240", "220", "200", "180", "160", "140", "120", "100", "80", "60", "40", "30", "20"]   

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        barraNav
        Spacer()
            VStack {
                NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Test ROSSO/VERDE")) {
                    Picker(selection: $valoreTestSelected, label: Text("Test Rosso/Verde")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< valoreTest.count) {
                                Text(self.valoreTest[$0])
                                    .onReceive([self.valoreTestSelected].publisher.first()) { value in
                                        risultatoRG = self.valoreTest[valoreTestSelected]
                                        
                                        debugPrint(risultatoRG)
```

DataManager file:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DataManager: ObservableObject {

let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void,Never>()


var storage : [AppModel] = [] {
    didSet {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

typealias Storage = [AppModel]

var filePath : String = ""

init() {caricaDati() }
```

AppModel File:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

var difettoCliente : String = "Protan"
var risultatoRG : String = "300"
var risultatoVB : String = "300"
var risultatoVV : String = "300"
var tipoDifetto : String = "300"
var risultatoRGCorretto : String = "300"
var lenteScelta :String?

class AppModel : Codable, Identifiable, ObservableObject  {
    
    var id : UUID = UUID()
    var nome : String
    var cognome : String
    var indirizzo : String
    var città : String
    var telefono : String
    var sphDx : String = "0.00"
    var cylDx : String = "0.00"
    var axDx : String = "0"
    var addizione : String = "+0.00"
    var sphSx : String = "0.00"
    var cylSx : String = "0.00"
    var axSx : String = "0"
    var note: String
    var risultatoRG : String = "300"

init(nome: String, cognome: String, indirizzo: String, città: String, telefono: String, sphDx: String, cylDx: String, axDx: String, sphSx: String, cylSx : String, axSx: String, addizione: String, note :String, risultatoRG : String) {
        self.nome = nome
        self.cognome = cognome
        self.indirizzo = indirizzo
        self.città = città
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.sphDx = sphDx
        self.cylDx = cylDx
        self.axDx = axDx
        self.sphSx = sphSx
        self.cylSx = cylSx
        self.axSx = axSx
        self.addizione = addizione
        self.note = note
        self.risultatoRG = risultatoRG
    }
   
    func aggiornaUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
```

Comment: Where is the array that you want to update?

Comment: I posted below a part of datamanger file.

Comment: nesting `ObservableObject` like you do is not a good idea, especially an array of `AppModel`.
 It will result in many problems. Restructure your code,
 possibly using `struct` for your `AppModel` and
 using the more modern `@Published var storage : [AppModel]`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to give a complete example using @Published, so there is no more need for Combine. Hope this gives you a start

```
import SwiftUI

struct AppModel : Identifiable, Codable  {
    
    var id : UUID = UUID()
    var nome : String
    var risultatoRG : String
    
    init(nome: String, risultatoRG : String) {
        self.nome = nome
        self.risultatoRG = risultatoRG
    }
}

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var storage : [AppModel] = []
        
    init() {
        // test data
        for i in 0..<10 {
            let newEntry = AppModel(nome: "nome \(i)", risultatoRG: "100")
            storage.append(newEntry)
        }
    }
}


struct ListView: View {
    
    // create data storage once! – can also be done at App level
    @StateObject var myData = DataManager()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(myData.storage) { entry in
                    NavigationLink {
                        TestView(data: myData, entry: entry)
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(entry.nome)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(entry.risultatoRG)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TestView: View {
    
    // passed down data storage – you could also do it via @EnvironmentObject
    @ObservedObject var data: DataManager
    var entry: AppModel

    init(data: DataManager, entry: AppModel) {
        self._data = ObservedObject(initialValue: data)
        self.entry = entry
        // setting the initial values for the @State vars
        self._nomeInput = State(initialValue: entry.nome)
        self._valoreInput = State(initialValue: entry.risultatoRG)
    }
    
    @State var nomeInput: String
    @State var valoreInput: String
    
    var valoreTest : [String] = ["300", "280", "260", "240", "220", "200", "180", "160", "140", "120", "100", "80", "60", "40", "30", "20"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            TextField("Nome", text: $nomeInput)
            Section(header: Text("Test ROSSO/VERDE")) {
                
                Picker("Test Rosso/Verde", selection: $valoreInput) {
                    ForEach(valoreTest, id: \.self) { valore in
                        Text(valore)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            // usually you would put this update as a method into the Datamanager class
            if let index = data.storage.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == entry.id}) {
                // telling the ObservedObject that something will change and it has to update the UI
                data.objectWillChange.send()
                data.storage[index].nome = nomeInput
                data.storage[index].risultatoRG = valoreInput
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I am a real newbie and before this my "app" gives a lot of troubles.... thanks anyway!